# How to run a Notify.js file for receive a pushnotification which is designd in phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to implement a Pushnotification in Phonegap 2.9.1 in android. I done till getting regId after this how can i receive a pushnotification,I also created a Notify.js file which is below and when i run this Notify.js file in cmd like this "DemoPush > node notify.js" its give me error can not fine this module,So how can i run this and how can i receive pushnotification in phonegap 2.9.1. Any one can tell me please? I am newly in Phonegap

Notify.js

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();


var sender = new gcm.Sender('APIKey');
var registrationIds = [];


message.addData('message',"\u270C Peace, Love \u2764 and PhoneGap \u2706!");
message.addData('title','Push Notification Sample' );
message.addData('msgcnt','3'); 
message.addData('soundname','beep.wav'); 

message.timeToLive = 300;


registrationIds.push('regId');


sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (result) {
     console.log(result);
     alert(result)
});
```

Comment: You need to insall node gcm

Comment: I aleardy installed this. How can i run this "node notify.js"?